# Why have I this error?

Tags: android, api, libraries

I am using last.fm API from here http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/

I downloaded it to my workspace, checked it as library, and imported it to my project...
The problem comes when I try to use one method of the API

```
Artist[] artist = LastFmServer.searchForArtist("hatebreed");
```

I dont know why, it says

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method searchForArtist(String) from the type LastFmServer
```

But I have another error trying to solve it. It causes this line

```
String artist = Artist.getName();

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getName() from the type Artist
```

its my first time using APIs, and i started getting tired of these errors, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other said you need to `Instantiate` `LastFmServer` like

```
LastFmServer mLastFmServer= new LastFmServer();
```

and then called you method like

```
Artist[] artist = mLastFmServer.searchForArtist("hatebreed");
```

Comment: if I do that i get "Cannot instantiate the type LastFmServer" error in your first line :( but this doesnt give any error: LastFmServer server = AndroidLastFmServerFactory.getServer();

Comment: I guess you are able to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/11924018/1436931..so now what is your problem? The main problem is, as also mentioned by others that you need to instantiate the `LastFmServer` with some `Default settings`

Comment: After solving the problem from link it seems that i got it working... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate a `LastFmServer` and `Artist` with `new` (or the appropriate factory method.

Comment: is this ok? LastFmServer server = AndroidLastFmServerFactory.getServer();

Answer (score 0):

You need to **instantiate** the respective objects of **LastFmServer** and **Artist** by using `new`.

```
LastFmServer lastFmServerObj = new LastFmServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the methods through a object and not make a static reference.

I'm guessing you'd create an `LastFmServer` like so (depending on the constructor).

```
LastFmServer object = new LastFmServer();
```

I hope this helps.