# Why toString() returns an hexadecimal code?

Tags: android, tostring, last.fm

I have this written in my app

```
LastFmServer server = AndroidLastFmServerFactory.getServer();
Artist[] results;
results = server.searchForArtist("Hatebreed"); 
Log.e("", results[2].toString());
```

Why does this code make this appear in logcat?

```
fm.last.api.Artist@2bf03488
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because that class doesn't implement its own toString, so you end up calling the one inherited from `java.lang.Object` that gives you the class name and its hash.

Comment: so what have i to do to appear the string?

Comment: You should find that class' documentation, but probably it's something like `results[2].name` or `results[2].getName()`; most probably the second.

Comment: It's doesn't **override** `toString`. It's already implemented by `Object`

Comment: a tip for future, In your IDE(Eclipse..) when you make a Object of a custom class then you can always put a `. dot` after that Object like in your case `results[0].` and then press `Ctrl + space` for `intellisense` :)